# Replace column references in values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has two columns (id and word). I have an other table which has a data column and its value references the word in the first table. Here is a sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE `words` (
  `id` TINYINT,
  `word` VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `words` VALUES (1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three');

CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `data` TEXT
);

INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('foo=bar\nword=one'), ('word=three');
```

I would like to replace the references of words to ids. So `word=one` would become `word=1`, `word=three` would become `word=3` and so on. I tried this query, but it doesn't work:

```
UPDATE `data`, `words` SET `data`.`data` = REPLACE(`data`.`data`, CONCAT('word=', `words`.`word`), CONCAT('word=', `words`.`id`));
```

Any suggestion or idea how to achieve what I want? Thanks!

Edit: Forgot to mention that data column is in INI format, so other key-value pairs can be in fields too. Adjusted the example.

Edit: Thanks to the idea of @nortphole I managed to build the query that I need:

```
UPDATE `data` SET `data`.`data` = REPLACE(`data`.`data`, CONCAT('word=', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`.`data`, 'word=', -1), '\n', 1)), CONCAT('word=', (SELECT `id` FROM `words` WHERE `words`.`word` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`.`data`, 'word=', -1), '\n', 1))));
```

Comment: This isn't good design, you shouldn't have those fields combined on one column. As it is, there is no practical difference between having `'word=one'` or `'word=1'`. Do you want this to do dynamic SQL?

Comment: "but it doesn't work" What specifically happens? Do you get an error message? Are any rows modified at all?

Comment: @MarkByers No, I don't get an error message. In the example, `word=one` is replaced to `word=1`, but `word=three` not.

Comment: @Lamak I know it's a bad design, but this is an existing application, and I can't change it now. The value of the data column is in INI format, so there can be more key-value pairs in a field, I just made the example simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE data 
   SET data = CONCAT('word=',(SELECT id 
                                FROM words 
                               WHERE words.word = SUBSTRING_INDEX(data.data,'=',-1)))
```

Sorry, I don't have MySql here to test it out (sepcifically make sure the SUBSTRING is getting everything after 'word=')

EDIT:
I use substring_index with a -1 to get me the last index of the = sign.

Comment: This works fine for the sample data. The problem is that the data column is in INI format, so `foo=bar\nword=one` (where \n is a new line character) can be a value too. In this case your solution doesn't work. Looks like I made the example too simple, sorry for that.

Comment: @GergoErdosi - no worries, but why don't you update your question with actual data in your current problem so I (and others) can work the actual issue.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it's still not enough. It's possible that `word=one` is in the middle of two other key-value pairs.

Comment: Never mind, you gave me a very good idea with SUBSTRING_INDEX. Updated the question with the query that I needed. Thanks for your help!